# Microsoft graph API return ExtensionError when creating subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, subscription

I have an application that uses MS Graph API to subscribe to calendar events. For most of the users this works fine, however, for certain users https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions always fail with `ExtensionError`.
For the same user manually triggered sync works fine.

Other thread here say the issue got fixed for them over time but I am facing this issue for a long time now.

Example error:

```
Error message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The requested user '<user@email.com>' is invalid.]

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Prefer : IdType=ImmutableId
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.2
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.2
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
{"changeType":"created,updated,deleted","clientSta[...]

404 : Not Found
[...]
```

Comment: Could you please share the whole error response with requestid and timestamp and aslo with the payload you are using?

Comment: Whats special about the user? Is it an older exchange mailbox moved to cloud?

Comment: Does the issue is intermittent or consistent?

Comment: Does the above helped you?